# Subquery returned more then 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big query but know the problem is coming from this part because when I added more then a row with the same mat_emp, I started to get the error in my program:

```
 ISNULL((SELECT  IIF( getdate() between  start_file and end_file, CAST(1 AS BIT),CAST(0 AS BIT)) from Xtable where mat_emp = E.mat_emp),0) as bool_value
```

Using TOP is not an option because I want to go through all records and I can't manage to understand how can I use `IN` in this case.

If a user have a record in `XTable`, It will check If `getdate` is between the `start_file` and `end_file`. If that's the case, It should return 1, If not, it should return 0. and I'm using `ISNULL` because If a user have no records there, It should return 0 too.

The full query:

```
SELECT MAT_EMP
    , Prenom_EMP
    , NOM_EMP
    , CODE_STR
    , ISNULL((SELECT PRENOM_EMP + ' ' + NOM_EMP from EMPLOYE where MAT_EMP = E.EMP_MAT_EMP),'Aucun') as Responsable
    , ISNULL(E.EMP_MAT_EMP,0) as EMP_MAT_EMP
    , (SELECT IS_ACTIVATED from USERS where USER_ID = E.USER_ID) as is_activated
    , ISNULL(USER_ID,0) as USER_ID
    , E.CODE_FONC
    , F.NOM_FONC
    , DN_EMP
    , TEL_EMP
    , DATE_RECRUTEMENT_EMP
    , ISNULL((SELECT  IIF( getdate() between  dc_debut and dc_fin, CAST(1 AS BIT),CAST(0 AS BIT)) from demande_conge where mat_emp = E.mat_emp),0) as is_on_vacation  
from EMPLOYE E 
INNER JOIN FONCTION F ON E.CODE_FONC = F.CODE_FONC
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: It's not possible to help you because it's not possible to tell what you're trying to do from just your broken code.

Comment: @D-Shih Edited the OP, thank you.

Comment: Ok, and what if a user have more than one record in XTable?

Comment: added the full query as well.

Comment: @TabAlleman It should return 1 as well. If any of the records start_file and end_file are between today's date, It should return 1.

Comment: Added some formatting to that wall of text query. It is obvious that at least one of your subqueries is returning more than 1 row. Maybe both of them. You need to figure out what that is really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write `LEFT JOIN` instead of a subquery. and use `CASE WHEN` to write the condition.

```
SELECT mat_emp, 
       prenom_emp, 
       nom_emp, 
       code_str, 
       Isnull((SELECT prenom_emp + ' ' + nom_emp 
               FROM   employe 
               WHERE  mat_emp = E.emp_mat_emp), 'Aucun') AS Responsable, 
       Isnull(E.emp_mat_emp, 0)                          AS EMP_MAT_EMP, 
       (SELECT is_activated 
        FROM   users 
        WHERE  user_id = E.user_id)                      AS is_activated, 
       Isnull(user_id, 0)                                AS USER_ID, 
       E.code_fonc, 
       F.nom_fonc, 
       dn_emp, 
       tel_emp, 
       date_recrutement_emp, 
       Isnull(CASE WHEN Getdate() BETWEEN d.dc_debut AND d.dc_fin THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,0) AS is_on_vacation
FROM   employe E 
       INNER JOIN fonction F 
               ON E.code_fonc = F.code_fonc 
        LEFT JOIN 
        demande_conge d ON d.mat_emp = E.mat_emp
```

Comment: That apparently did the trick but I can't select MAT_EMP just like that. If I put E.mat_EMP (first line), I will get multiple results (depending on how much rows I have in the demande_conge) table. Should I use Distinct?

Comment: You can try to use `IIF(
 (SELECT COUNT(*)
 from demande_conge d
 where d.mat_emp = E.mat_emp and getdate() between d.dc_debut and d.dc_fin) > 0,1,0
 ) as is_on_vacation ` in your query to select `is_on_vacation ` colnum

Answer (score 0):

> If any of the records start_file and end_file are between today's
>   date, It should return 1.

In that case, instead of `IIF`, you should use [IF EXISTS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to check if any row exists for that employee with that date filter.